# Trying to find the distance between two LatLng objects using googlemaps api and javascript

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, distance

Hi I am playing with html5 geolocation and have used the  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail) object to get the users position.

In the success function I then created a variable called coords to hold the coordinates and a variable coords2 to hold other coordinates i made up.

```
 var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude position.coords.longitude); 
 var coords2 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.8619788, -4.2867578);
```

Using the following code I position the two points on the map as markers:

```
 var mapOptions = {

                zoom: 16,
                center: coords,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

        };


 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);  


 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: coords,
                map: map,
                title: "Your current location!"
        });


 var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: coords2,
                map: map,
                title: "Nearest Person!"
        });
```

What I then want to do is work out the distance between these points. I cant seem to find a method that does it.

Here is what I am trying:

```
  var distance = computeDistanceBetween(coords, coords2);
  alert(distance);
```

Any idead what im doing wrong?Cheers!
Paul

Answer (score 3):

In v2, you can do

```
coords.distanceFrom(coords2);
```

It's documented at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GLatLng

**Edit**: I think you may be using v3. If so, I believe you'll need the full namespace:

> var distance =
>   google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(coords,
>   coords2);

Answer (score 3):

There is the [computeDistanceBetween()](http://code.google.com/intl/el/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html#Distance) in the new [V3 Geometry Library](http://code.google.com/intl/el/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html)

Answer (score 2):

The google.maps.geometry library is not loaded by default. You have to explicitly specify to load it also, in the bootstrap request:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=true_or_false"></script>
```